# el-get-executable-find: The command named 'hg' can not be found with `executable-find'

Tags: emacs

Today I tried to configure `python` development in `emacs`.

I installed `pymacs, pycomplete+ , python-mode, python-pep8` with `el-get`.

When i tried to install `rope` I got this error

> el-get-executable-find: The command named 'hg' can not be found with `executable-find'

then,when I delete the `config` about `"el-get"`

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get/el-get")   
(unless (require 'el-get nil 'noerror)`    
  (with-current-buffer   
      (url-retrieve-synchronously  
       "https://raw.github.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el")   
    (goto-char (point-max))   
    (eval-print-last-sexp))) 
(el-get 'sync)
```

the error disappear.

Anyone could help me to fix it?

Comment: Did you install Mercurial at all?

Comment: lunaryorn: you should probably post that as a proper answer so that it can be accepted, and clarify that `hg` is the Mercurial VCS' main executable. Undoubtedly the el-get recipe in question needs to clone a Mercurial repository.

Comment: phils: but i never meet this error before...i have already installed Mercurial ,just now.it seems nothing help.(install with .mpkg file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already commented, the mercurial dvc command,"hg", was not found in path.

Once noticed Emacs didn't load all executables in emacs variable "exec-path" as in $PATH. This happened when started from a windows-system button. Maybe when started from console it's gone.

Check exec-path, if it includes the directory displayed by "type hg".
Adding it to exec-path via init-file might be an option in this case.